# zend framework - how not to wait for upload if some validator fails?

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form, zend-form-element

i have a form with *various elements* and a *file upload*, sometimes the user has to wait for the upload to finish only to see he wrote something wrong(some element didn't pass validation).

Is it possible that if some validator fails on any element of the form, all other validation stops and the form returns immediately **without waiting for the upload to finish** ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, of course.

- Use Javascript validation in addition to server side validation (never use only js validation). With Javascript validation you can give the user feedback instantly, even while filling in a particular form field.
- Break the Zend_Form validation chain by passing `TRUE` as the second parameter when adding validators to a form, e.g. `$element->addValidator('alnum', true)`. `TRUE` means the form validation will immediately return.

Comment: what i mean is that if the user doesn't type in a required field, even if i break the validator chain, it only breaks it on that element, not on all elements

Comment: @markus: But for a form with an upload, doesn't the server-side validation begin only _after_ the entire post contents are received? In that case, doesn't the user still have to wait for his big upload, irrespective of whether you break on failure for the validators?

Comment: Yeah, that's why you need to check everything with Javascript first, if everything is fine on the client side, the probability that validators on the server side will return false is very low.

Comment: i've used some client side validation in the end, though the trick with the chain didn't work

Answer (score 2):

You might want to validate the form fields individually using Ajax, before submitting the form. This way, the users will get early feedback without having the overhead of the file upload.

I used the following tutorial to do it, and it worked fine for me:

http://www.zendcasts.com/ajaxify-your-zend_form-validation-with-jquery/2010/04/

Hope that helps,

Comment: i was hoping to do it php way on the server side

Comment: It's actually done on the server side. What the Ajax part is doing is just submitting the partial form contents to the server, which validates them using `$form->isValidPartial()`.

Answer (score 2):

Please Find the solution i think this will help you

```
    <?php

class Test_Form_ItemCreate extends Zend_Form {

    public function init() {
        $this->setAction('/test/item/create')
                ->setMethod('post');
        $name = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('SellerName');
        $name->setLabel('Name:')
                ->setOptions(array('size' => '35'))
                ->setRequired(true)
                ->addFilter('StringTrim');

//handling images..   
        $images = new Zend_Form_Element_File('images');
        $images->setMultiFile(3)
                ->addValidator('IsImage')
                ->addValidator('Size', false, '204800')
                ->addValidator('Extension', false, 'jpg,png,gif')
                ->addValidator('ImageSize', false, array(
                    'minwidth' => 150,
                    'minheight' => 150,
                    'maxwidth' => 150,
                    'maxheight' => 150
                ))
                ->setValueDisabled(true);//the value will not be available.. while checking the file is valid or not.this is very important

        // attach element to form    
        $this->addElement($images);
        $this->addElement($name);
    }

}

class Test_ItemController extends Zend_Controller_Action {

    public function createAction() {
        // generate input form
        $form = new Test_Form_ItemCreate;
        $this->view->form = $form;
        if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
            if ($form->isValid($this->getRequest()->getPost())) {

                //moving of files if it is valid only
                $form->images->setDestination('/tmp/uploads');
                $adapter = $form->images->getTransferAdapter();
                for ($x = 0; $x < $form->images->getMultiFile(); $x++) {
                    $xt = @pathinfo($adapter->getFileName('images_' . $x . '_'), PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
                    $adapter->clearFilters();
                    $adapter->addFilter('Rename', array(
                        'target' => sprintf('%d_%d.%s', $id, ($x + 1), $xt),
                        'overwrite' => true
                    ));
                    $adapter->receive('images_' . $x . '_');
                }

                $this->_helper->getHelper('FlashMessenger')->addMessage('Your submission has been accepted as item #' . $id . '. A moderator will review it and, if approved, it will appear on the site within 48 hours.');
                $this->_redirect('/test/item/success');
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Please note setValueDisabled(true) in Test_Form_ItemCreate

Comment: thank you, i didn't know about setValueDisabled(), but i went with javascript because even so the file still gets uploaded first, i tested it over low internet connection and i have to wait minutes... i gave the bounty to you for your effort